# Is it possible to have a 'jumpy' CAAnimation?

Tags: iphone, caanimation

I've looked through the documentation and books on this, but I seem to be missing out on it.

I am looking for a jumpy animation, something like x=0 to x=40, where it jumps from x=0 to x=5 to x=10 and so on.

Comment: I woud use a CAKeyframeAnimation for that.

Comment: I tried, but the modes are either linear, ease in/out, or default. Which I am not looking for..

Comment: You can give several key frames and the time intervals between the key frames. Therefore you can animate almost everything.

Comment: Jumpy as in not animate it at all. I want it to move from x=0, to x=5 directly, not x=0 to x=1 to x=2 to x=3 to x=4 to x=5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Simply set the `calculationMode` to `kCAAnimationDiscrete`.

Comment: Accept it as the answer as well. That way it won't get revived in the future.